# jQuery RTF Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, rtf

I have seen a lot of RTF editors out there, but I can't seem to find one that will let me preload RTF data and display it properly and then spit RTF data back out to me. Does anyone know of any good ones?

For example, if I had this:

```
<textarea id="rtf">
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
</textarea>
```

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that will display:

This is some **bold** text.

In an editable textarea and then give me back whatever changes they made in RTF, NOT HTML.

Comment: This is hard to find. Better change the goal and try to implement some external library as https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormatRTF as a plugin for your editor, or just use it to save content.

Answer (score 0):

[CuteEditor.NET](http://cutesoft.net/example/editrtf.aspx) seems to have this ability, although:

1. It requires an ASP.NET server-side process; and
2. My quick test determined that the formatting of the resulting RTF file doesn't match that displayed in the web GUI.
3. It's not a JQuery plugin.
4. It's commercial.